# Will the script on remote server keep running after ssh timeout?

Tags: linux

I'm running some script on remote server using ssh. The task is downloading images to remote server. I'm wondering will the script keep running after I log out the ssh session? Why? Could anyone explain in detail?

Comment: Off-topic: this question belongs to [superuser.com](http://superuser.com). Anyway, it's answered [here](http://superuser.com/questions/451057/keep-processes-alive-after-ssh-logout). The short answer -- use [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the script keep running after logout you need to detach it from the terminal and run it in the background:

```
nohup ./script.sh &
```

If you close the terminal where you launched a process in, the process will receive `SIGHUP` and unless it handles it this means the process will get terminated. `HUP` means *hang up*, like in a phone call.

The `nohup` command can be used to start a process and prevent it from `SIGHUP` signals getting send to it. An alternative would be to use the bash builtin `disown`, which does basically the same:

```
./script.sh &
disown %1
```

Note that the `1` represents the job id. If you running multiple processes in the background you need to specify the correct job id.